# value from db contains php variable name ('hello $name') , how show it correctly?

Tags: php

from db i'm getting a string that contains php variable name like 'hello $name' , i don't know how to show it correctly :

ex : 
lets say i have function show name :

```
function echoName($name){    
          //call to db to get string (hello $name)
          $helloname = $row['helName'];
          echo $helloname; //lets say name = jinko it should print hello jinko
         //but it prints hello $name
         // i have tried "$helloname"; it doesn't work

}
```

in my case db contains:

```
Il tuo codice di prenotazione è $codicePrenotazione<br>Ricordiamo la data : $newDate
```

my code for function :

```
function sendEmail($cognome,$nome,$email,$codicePrenotazione,$date){

 require './dbconnection.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  $query = 'SELECT Azienda_Nome,Azienda_email_notifiche_smtp,Azienda_email_notifiche_utente ,Azienda_email_notifiche_pwd,Azienda_email_notifiche_porta,Azienda_email_notifiche_sicurezza ,Azienda_mex_utente FROM `aziende`';
  $stmt =$conn->query($query);
  $stmt->execute(); 
  $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

  $siteOwnersEmail = $row['Azienda_email_notifiche_utente'];
  $smtp =$row['Azienda_email_notifiche_smtp'];
  $password =$row['Azienda_email_notifiche_pwd'];
  $porta=strtolower( $row['Azienda_email_notifiche_porta']);
  $sicurezza=strtolower( $row['Azienda_email_notifiche_sicurezza']);
  $contact_message = $row['Azienda_mex_utente'];//this line contains the string 
  $nomeAzienda = $row['Azienda_Nome'];
  $conn = null;

  $newDate = date("d-m-Y H:i", strtotime($date)); 
   $name = $nome.' '.$cognome;
   $email = $email;
   $subject = 'Codice Prenotazione';

//etc etc 




}
```

Comment: can you provide your rest of the code.

Comment: @KunalRaut yes ofc , but i don't know if it is necessary

Comment: ok so just tell me that have you queried to database and if yes is `helName` a cloumn name in the table?

Comment: @KunalRaut look updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using something like [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/sprintf).

For example if you have this in your database:

```
Hello, your name is %s
```

You can format it like this:

```
echo sprintf($row["heName"], "Test");
```

Which will output:

```
Hello, your name is Test
```

If you **really** want to use PHP style variable names one way would be to  use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) to replace the variables with their respective value:

```
<?php

function format_string($string, $variables) {
    return preg_replace_callback("~\\$([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)~",
    function($match) use (&$variables) {
        $varname = $match[1];

        return $variables[$varname];
    }, $string);
}

echo format_string("Hello \$user", /* variable table */ [
    "user" => "Test"
]);
```

Comment: OP said the string is in this format: `hello $name`. Your answer doesn't work with that.  `sprintf` cannot evaluate that.

Comment: @SwetankPoddar Yes. That's why I phrased it "You're better off using sprintf".

Comment: @marco-a yes i can change it to sprintf but if i dont know how many variables are in the db string?

Comment: `return "variable contents";` doesn't really help.

Comment: @marco-a i think i will go for sprintf , but there is a  way to do it when you don't know the number of variables inside the string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)...

```php
$name = "jinko";
$helloname = "hello $name";
eval("\$helloname = \"$helloname\";");

echo $helloname; // prints: hello jinko
```

**warning: this can be dangerous as eval "executes" any PHP code. So use it only if the data coming from your database is safe.**

Comment: There are better approaches to solve this problem. `eval` should be the last defence.

Comment: @eval: There is a reason why it still exists. PHP documentation says "eval — Evaluate a string as PHP code".  Which is exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: No. OP is asking to replace variables in a string. Not to execute PHP